# WPF StaticResource передача параметра

Tags: wpf, xaml, анимация

Как в XAML передать параметр в стиль от определенного контрола?

Например

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="LoadRectAnimation">
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="#ffffff"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}}" Value="Visible">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="???" From="#ffffffff" To="#00ffffff" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"/>

                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </Window.Resources>



<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LoadRectAnimation}"/>
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LoadRectAnimation}"/>
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LoadRectAnimation}"/>
```

Для представленных Rectangle стиль один, и анимация должна быть одна, НО, с одним отличием - BeginTime должен быть указан к каждому элементу свой.

Как такое осуществить?

Comment: Сорри, не могу сходу придумать красивое решение. Удалю покамест ответ. В крайнем случае, можно сконструировать нужную анимацию в code-behind.

Comment: это то можно, но перегружать код не хотелось бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, прямого пути передать параметр я не нашёл. Обычный обходной путь — положить параметр в `ResourceDictionary` и подключить его при помощи `DynamicResource` — не работает, потому что `Storyboard` должна быть заморожена перед использованием, а значит, ссылка на динамические ресурсы вызовет исключение.

Давайте, однако, подумаем: что именно мы хотим? Мы хотим задать последовательность анимаций. Значит, они должны быть частью **общего** `Storyboard`, который должен просто запускать их одну за другой в нужный момент. Для этого стиль надо определить в общем контейнере для всех `Rectangle`'ов.

Небольшая проблема заключается в том, что `DataTrigger` нельзя использовать для `UIElement.Triggers`, поэтому нам нужно применить `Style` или `Template`. Поскольку нам нужно применять `Storyboard` для внутреннего элемента, из вариантов остаётся только `Template`. Поскольку для стандартных контролов нельзя установить `Template`, поместим всё в фиктивный `Control`.

Итого получается следующее решение:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#ffffff"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Rectangle Name="A"/>
                <Rectangle Name="B"/>
                <Rectangle Name="C"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Visible">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" From="#00ff0000" To="#ffff0000" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="A"/>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.5" From="#0000ff00" To="#ff00ff00" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="B"/>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1" From="#000000ff" To="#ff0000ff" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="C"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
```

Это, разумеется, не вполне то, что вы просили, но, думаю, решает вашу проблему: у вас уменьшается количество обвязочного кода.

Comment: хм.. при указании BeginTime="{DynamicResource получаю XAML parse error

Comment: @Ni55aN: А какую ошибку конкретно?

Comment: в том то и дело, что только исключение System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException и указывает на --- Задание свойства "System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "36" и позиция в строке "50" --- где у меня лишь  <Rectangle Width="16" Height="8" Margin="4,4,0,4" >

Comment: либо указав стиль в теле, как у Вас, тогда ругается на  <StaticResource ResourceKey="LoadRectAnimation"/>

Comment: @Ni55aN: Вы должны смотреть в InnerException :) Я сделал тестовый проект и заглянул, сейчас починю.

Comment: в иннере "Не удается зафиксировать данное дерево шкалы времени Storyboard для использования в различных потоках."

Comment: @Ni55aN: Угу, вижу проблему. Сейчас подумаю, как с ней бороться.

Comment: @Ni55aN: Переписал ответ полностью. Смотрите.